# How to assign multiple workers to one task at the same time

Tags: optaplanner

I have the requirement as follows: there are some tasks and some workers,

1. For any given task, we need one worker or a pair of workers with different levels at the same time.
2. For any given task, we must finish it before a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

1. define one worker or a combination with two workers as a human resource, assign the human resource object to the task.
2. write a hard constraint rule for the task's finish time. Punish it when the finish time is later than the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Kent's 2 options, there is a more complex scenario that requires:

Option 3: The **auto delay to last** design pattern.

- Give each `Task` 1 or more `TaskAssignment` instances. Some tasks only require only 1 `Worker`, so they only have 1 `TaskAssignment`. Those that require multiple workers, have multiple.
- 2 task assignments for the same task must start and end at the same time (the workers need to work together). **Delay until the last arriving worker.** So when worker 1 arrives at 10:00 and worker 2 arrives at 10:30, delay the worker 1 until 10:30 to start the task. So if the task takes 1 hour, both workers are done at 11:30 (so worker 1 will have lost half an hour, but the solver will automatically start avoiding that because of your existing soft constraints that already favor time efficiency)
- If 2 task assignments for the same task have the same worker, incur a hard constraint penalty.